# Issue in deserializing the current time in OffsetDateTime format

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, datetime

Here, when I deserialize the current time in OffsetDateTime format it is trimming of the 0 before Z.

For example, OffsetDateTime is 2023-06-20T06:59:31.400Z, it is converting to 2023-06-20T06:59:31.4Z

```
    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    jsonMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    jsonMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    jsonMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false); 
    jsonMapper.registerModule(new JSR310Module());"
```

I want to pass the value as this pattern "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" without trimming it.

Answer (score 0):

During deserialization with Jackson, milliseconds will be trimmed if they are in zeros.

This is an open issue.

You can refer the below link for solution:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/issues/76